# Returning ERC20 tokens accidentally sent to the DAI contract

Tags: erc-20, contract-invocation, dai

I don’t know if it’s the right place for it, but I’m taking a chance. Despite several years of daily use of ERC20 tokens, I unfortunately managed to make a mistake and send some ERC20 tokens to the DAI contract instead on another wallet. Here is the DAI contract address : 0x6B175474E89094C44Da98b954EedeAC495271d0F
Could you please tell me if there is a way to get those ERC20 tokens back? Maybe using the read & write features of Etherscan?
I am very sorry for the inconvenience and appreciate any help.

Best,

Answer (score 1):

You cannot transfer tokens from a contract address, unless that contract address has a function built-in to send a transaction or recover tokens in some way. It doesn't look like DAI has this built-in, so I'm afraid that your tokens are lost.

In the future, double check the address you're sending to, and send a small test transaction if you're moving a significant amount of funds.